# The correct empty/full icon for Trash

Tags: nautilus, icons, trash

I use the MacBuntu-OS icon package in my theme, but after recently rectifying a Trash root-permissions issue (not allowing me to delete, etc.) and rectifying a silly mistake I made by changing the icon (by restoring the home/user/.config/nautilus/desktop-metadata file), I have a new issue with the Trash icon.

The icons for empty and full, respectively, should (at least I think) be:

[image] [image]

which can be found in usr/share/icons/MacBuntu-OS/places/128.

Instead, the system is using the first image for empty (as it should) and then using this icon for full:

[image]

which can be found in usr/share/icons/MacBuntu-OS/status/96.

My question: is there some way of setting some kind of trash or icon parameter that it uses the first two icons?